# Pipeline out in map step don't always contains the output (reference doc) of the Flow

Tags: webmethods

Using the WebMethods 9.7 Designer, when I create a Flow Service, with a Map steps, the output pipeline of the map step don't always contains  the output of the Flow Service.

[image]
[image]

My Questions are :

- Is it a designer bug, or something I have not understand (i assume it's the second one, but i can't see what) ?
- How can i add my Reference Doc (already in in Output reference) in the pipeline out of the map step ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Designer only shows the service's output arguments in the very last step of your flow service on the right `Pipeline Out` side of the step's pipeline view, and it only does this as a hint to show you that **you** need to create them if they don't already exist by mapping something to them. Move your map step to be the last step in your flow service to see what I mean.

You can declare any variables you want in a map step's `Pipeline Out`, and then map values as required from the left `Pipeline In` side to the right `Pipeline Out` side.

The easiest way to get a variable with the same name and type as the service's output argument is to copy (`CTRL-C`) `SiebelMessage` from the `Input/Output` tab and then paste (`CTRL-V`) it into the right `Pipeline Out` side of the step in which you want to create it. You will then need to either map values to it or set values on it to actually create it: copying it into the `Pipeline Out` of a map step doesn't create the variable, it just creates a placeholder in the Designer UI into which you need to map or set values to actually create it in the pipeline.

The long way is to manually create a variable with the same name and type as the service's output argument by right-clicking on the right `Pipeline Out` side of the step's pipeline (or by clicking in the `Pipeline Out` area to give it focus and then choosing the `Insert a Variable` action on the pipeline toolbar) and inserting a new document reference variable with the name `SiebelMessage` and choose the same document reference that you used when you created the service's output argument.